# Updating lists in R

Tags: r, rscript

I have the following list in R and I want to replace all NULL in the list with zero. Is there a better way of doing this rather than iterating through the list?

```
$`2014-06-15`
NULL
$`2014-06-16`
[1] 7
$`2014-06-17`
[1] 17
$`2014-06-18`
[1] 24
$`2014-06-19`
[1] 8
$`2014-06-20`
[1] 11
$`2014-06-21`
NULL
$`2014-06-22`
[1] 1
$`2014-06-23`
[1] 20
$`2014-06-24`
[1] 21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to your solution, this way is easier and faster than replacing with a `for` loop and `if` statement.  Here's a short example.

```
> ( temp <- list(A = NULL, B = 1:5) )
# $A
# NULL
# 
# $B
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5

> temp[sapply(temp, is.null)] <- 0
> temp
# $A
# [1] 0
#
# $B
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind solved it.

temp is my list of dates above

```
allDates <- names(temp)
for (i in allDates) {
  if (is.null(temp[[i]])) 
    temp[[i]] <- 0
}
```

Comment: Actually a better way is `lapply(temp, function(x) if(is.null(x)) 0 else x)`